# Vim: How to declare that a file with a certain name should be of some file type?

Tags: vim, neovim

I have a file named `ini` which receives no syntax highlighting since there is no file extension to help identify the file type. How would I go about declaring that all files which are named `ini` should be of type `dosini`?

[image: No file type]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:h ftdetect` may help you. Basically it is

`autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.ini setfiletype dosini`

Comment: I totally forgot that you could also use `BufNewFile` and `BufRead` on file names.
I did `autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead ini setfiletype dosini`, which works, thanks.

Comment: @Krit Please read `:h ftdetect` anyway. There are 4 different methods where to put that line, depending on what you want.